# Adding RTSP over TCP support to VLC RTSP Server

Tags: vlc, rtsp

We have recently developed an application using [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) streaming features. A new thing that we need is to have an RTSP server supporting RTSP/TCP (RTSP over TCP). Unfortunately, VLC does not support RTSP/TCP.

We will be glad if someone shares a sample VLC code with RTSP/TCP capability or help us to add RTSP/TCP feature to VLC software package.

Regards,